# Рекурсивно построить список в Perl

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте!
У меня задание построить рекурсивно список из хеш-массивов, что-то вроде таблицы, упорядоченный по ключу односвязный список, содержащий сведения о студентах (ФИО, номер зачетной книжки, номер группы, специальность, год рождения). В качестве ключа использовать номер зачетной книжки. 
Есть программа-пример. Но она не работает.

```
use encoding 'cp1251', STDOUT => 'cp866', STDIN => 'cp866';
#! /bin/usr/perl
#Добавление в список
sub insert 
{ my ($item, $p)= shift @_;

unless ($item)
{ $item ={};                          #Анонимный хеш, создаем запись
$item->{INFO}= $p;
$item->{NEXT}=undef;   #Последний элемент в списке
$_[0]=$item;
return;
}
if ($item->{INFO} == $p)
{print"Такое значение уже есть в списке!\n";}
else
{ print"Новая запись в списке!\n";
insert ($item->{NEXT},$p);}
}

#Печать списка
sub list_print
{  my ($item) = shift;
unless ($item) { return;}
else
{   print "$item->{INFO}";
list_print ($item->{NEXT});  }}

#Главная программа
if (defined $head) {undef $head;}
while ($value = <>)
{ insert ($head, $value);
}
print "\n";
list_print ($head);
```

Немного непонятно, зачем голова списка делается  undef, может она и остается неопределенной..Может кто-нибудь найдет ошибку в этом коде, почему он не работает..

Comment: и что программа печатает?

Comment: И что же Вы тут хотели написать? Что такое

     my ($item, $p)= shift @_;

и зачем

     $_[0]=$item;

(оно же вроде уже и не используется). И проверка на дублирование элемента -- только для последнего элемента в списке? И где тут хотя бы малейшее упоминание об упорядочении списка? Опишите поподробнее задачу, если не трудно

Comment: @alexlz, если немного поприличней переписать insert(), то видно: проматывается весь список от головы, при добавлении каждого элемента, и по каждому элементу списка идёт проверка. 


`$_[0]=$item` здесь используется для модификации аргумента (ну, то есть того, что передаётся аргументом).


В общем, всё в худших традициях перла сделано.

Comment: @klopp торможу. Действительно insert проматывает весь список, радостно печатая для каждого существующего узла

       print"Новая запись в списке!\n";

Но вопрос насчёт присвоения `$p` в insert остаётся.

Comment: shift тут вообще не при чём. Таким образом создаётся новый элемент списка:

    $item->{NEXT} = undef;         # сейчас тут пустота
    foo( $item->{NEXT}, 'data' );  # а после вызова - 'data'
    sub foo
    {
        my ( undef, $data ) = @_;
        $_[0] = $data;          
    }

Фактически это как бы такая запись: 

    void foo( bar **baz, bar *data )
    {
        *baz = new bar(data);    
    }

Но использовать $_[] для возврата в реальнх "боевых" условиях я бы не стал, разве что в однострочниках уровня:

    sub trim
    {
        $_[0] =~ s/^\s|\s$//gs;
    }

Comment: @klopp Ok, но что значит вот это вот:

     my ($item, $p)= shift @_;

Comment: Да фигня это полная :) То есть синтаксически верно, но по сути имелось в виду, наверное, что-то из:

    my ($item, $p) = (shift, shift);
    my ($item, $p) = (shift @_, shift @_);
    my ($item, $p) = @_;

P.S. Если речь о том, что после `shift` присвоение элементам `$_[]` уже идёт чёрт знает куда, то да, для получения аргументов стоит использовать последний вариант. Либо оказазаться от подобных выкрутасов в принципе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Долго и внимательно читал условие. Долго и внимательно пытался продраться через абракадабру кода (за знание основ перла - твёрдая двойка). Так ничего и не понял. Поэтому попробую включить телепатический орган.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @data =
(   
    [ 1, 'Ivan',  1990 ],
    [ 2, 'Mary',  1970 ],
    [ 3, 'Sam',   1980 ]
);
my %list;

add_to_list( \%list, \@data );
print_list( \%list );

sub print_list
{
    my ( $list ) = @_;

    print Dumper( $list->{INFO} ) if $list and $list->{INFO};

    print_list( $list->{NEXT} ) if $list and $list->{NEXT};
}

sub add_to_list
{
    my ( $list, $data ) = @_;

    my $item = shift @{$data};

    if( $item )
    {
        $list->{INFO} = $item;
        $list->{NEXT} = {};
        add_to_list( $list->{NEXT}, $data );
    }
}
```

Теперь бонусы.

1) Если отслеживается номер зачётки (первый элемент в [[[[[@data](/users/4262/dataman)](/users/4262/dataman)](/users/4262/dataman)](/users/4262/dataman)](/users/4262/dataman)), то имеет смысл завести дополнительный хэш, а не бегать по всему списку, это будет намного быстрей:

```
my %list;
my %added;

# ...

sub add_to_list
{
    my ( $list, $data ) = @_;
    my $item = shift @{$data};
    if( $item )
    {
        if( $added{$item->[0]} )
        {
            print "Already in list: $item->[0]\n";
            add_to_list( $list, $data );
        }
        else
        {
            $added{$item->[0]} = 1;
            $list->{ITEM} = $item;
            $list->{NEXT} = {};
            add_to_list( $list->{NEXT}, $data );
        }
    }
}
```

2) Если так важно вводить данные из STDIN, то вводим сразу всё, разделитель в полях - запятая, конец данных - пустая строка:

```
my @data;
while( <> )
{
    chomp; 
    last unless $_;
    push @data, [split ','];
}
```

Я не знаю, что именно требуется, но, надеюсь, хоть что-то понятней станет. Но на всякий случай приведу к читаемому виду оригинальный insert():

```
sub insert_student
{
    my ( $list, $student ) = @_;
    unless( $list )
    {
        $list->{INFO} = $student;
        $_[0] = $list;
        print "New student added: $student\n";
    }
    else
    {      
        if( $list->{INFO} == $student )
        {
            print "Already in list: $student\n";
        }
        else
        {
            insert_student( $list->{NEXT}, $student );
        }
    }
}
```

Или, с учётом того, что $student - массив (хэш был бы лучше, но да ладно):

```
sub insert_student
{
    my ( $list, $student ) = @_;
    unless( $list )
    {
        $list->{INFO} = $student;
        $_[0] = $list;
        print "New student added: $student->[0]\n";
    }
    else
    {      
        if( $list->{INFO}->[0] == $student->[0] )
        {
            print "Already in list: $student->[0]\n";
        }
        else
        {
            insert_student( $list->{NEXT}, $student );
        }
    }
}
```